# linker script, what do region attributes do exactly?

Tags: linker-scripts

In linker scripts I typically see that flash is marked with rx

```
MEMORY
{
  /* Define each memory region */
  PROGRAM_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0x400000 /* 4M bytes (alias Flash) */  
  SRAM_DTC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000 /* 64K bytes (alias RAM) */  
  SRAM_ITC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 0x10000 /* 64K bytes (alias RAM2) */  
  SRAM_OC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20200000, LENGTH = 0x20000 /* 128K bytes (alias RAM3) */  
  BOARD_SDRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 0x1e00000 /* 30M bytes (alias RAM4) */  
  NCACHE_REGION (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x81e00000, LENGTH = 0x200000 /* 2M bytes (alias RAM5) */  
}
```

But I can still erase and write sections in flash when my app is running. What does this `r` attribute imply/limit/mean then?

Comment: Those attributes are going to be enforced by the operating system. If you're running on an embedded system, you likely don't have an operating system to enforce this type of memory protection.

Comment: @CodyGray thx (yes, using this on an mcu indeed) ! mystery solved :) So they are pointless in embedded context all together? Or is there still some convention to use them for meaningful insights?